# Hummingbird adds unwanted file paths to clip-path URLS

Tags: css, wordpress, caching, hummingbird

I have named clip-paths throughout my site, and when I try to use them like so:

`clip-path:url("#mask-circle");`

Hummingbird adds an entire path to the URL, as if named path is a file I can link to:

`clip-path:url("https://www._______.com/wp-content/themes/_______/assets/styles/#mask-circle");`

Is there anyway to disable this, or at least flag a line of styles to leave as-is?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67141856/css-clip-path-source-url-gets-change-while-using-in-solution). Any solution?

Comment: @Ronak We ended up having to exclude those styles from the optimizer. It just seems to be a complete oversight by Hummingbird.

Comment: @thirteen - you mean, this is something because of optimizer who adds paths to css url?

Comment: @Ronak Correct. In this case, it appeared to be "over-optimizing."