# css clip-path source url gets change while using in solution

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, clip-path

I need to override highcharts plotband div through css clip-path(source url - image-1) that I achieved in jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1ojphezv/1/ which is working fine for me.

[image: jsfiddle code, source url pointing to the correct div]

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            height: 250,
            plotBorderColor: '#BFBFBF',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            spacingRight: 1,
            spacingBottom: 0,
            marginBottom: 87
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'left',
            itemStyle: {
                color: "#000",
                fontSize: "11px !important",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                textOverflow: null
            },
            symbolWidth: 20,
            x: 17,
            itemMarginBottom: 6
        },
        xAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.06,
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                week: '%b-%d-%Y',
                month: '%b-%d-%Y',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: "10px !important",
                    color: "#000"
                }
            },
            gridLineColor: "transparent",
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: "transparent",
            tickLength: 0,
            style: {
                fontSize: "10px !important",
                color: "#000"
            }
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                tickInterval: 20,
                plotBands: [
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(204,0,0)',
                        from: 0,
                        to: 30.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(226,113,113)',
                        from: 31,
                        to: 44.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(247,209,34)',
                        from: 45,
                        to: 54.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(136,207,136)',
                        from: 55,
                        to: 68.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(68,180,68)',
                        from: 69,
                        to: 87.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(0,153,0)',
                        from: 88,
                        to: 100,
                        zIndex: 3
                    }
                ],
                gridLineWidth: 0.5,
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    x: -7,
                    y: 5,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                linkedTo: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        ],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter() {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    inactive: {
                        opacity: 1
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                threshold: 0, // let zero values have some height
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    radius: 2
                },
                minPointLength: 10,
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: false,
            shared: false,
            followPointer: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.y;
            }
        },
        series: [
        {
                    "color": "rgb(0,187,221)",
                    "data": [
                    {"x":1601490600000,"y":25},
                    {"x":1601577000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1601663400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1601749800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1601836200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1601922600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1602009000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602095400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1602181800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1602268200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1602354600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1602441000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1602527400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1602613800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1602700200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1602786600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1602873000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602959400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1603045800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1603132200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1603218600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1603305000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1603391400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1603477800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1603564200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1603650600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1603737000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1603823400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1603909800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1603996200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1604169000000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1604255400000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1604341800000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1604428200000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1604514600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1604601000000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1604687400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1604773800000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1604860200000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1604946600000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1605033000000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1605119400000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1605205800000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1605292200000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1605378600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1605465000000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1605551400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1605637800000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1605724200000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1605810600000,"y":44}
                 ],
                    "name": 'ABC',
                    "type": 'spline'
                },
                {
                    "color": "rgb(154,2,42)",
                    "data": [
                    {"x":1601490600000,"y":50},
                    {"x":1601577000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1601663400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1601749800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1601836200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1601922600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602009000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1602095400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1602181800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1602268200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1602354600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602441000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602527400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1602613800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1602700200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1602786600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602873000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1602959400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1603045800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1603132200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1603218600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1603305000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1603391400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1603477800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1603564200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1603650600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1603737000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1603823400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1603909800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1603996200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1604169000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1604255400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1604341800000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1604428200000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1604514600000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1604601000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1604687400000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1604773800000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1604860200000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1604946600000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1605033000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1605119400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1605205800000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1605292200000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1605378600000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1605465000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1605551400000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1605637800000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1605724200000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1605810600000,"y":85}
                    ],
                    "name": 'XYZ',
                    "type": 'spline'
                }
        ]
    });
```

```css
.highcharts-plot-bands-3 {
  clip-path: url(#clip-triangle);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 95%"></div>
  <svg>
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip-triangle">
                <polygon points="0 0, 100 0, 100 0, 50 0, 50 250, -50 250" />
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</div>
```

The same code when I integrate into my project/solution then clip-path css source url gets change and it starts pointing to the absolute path (image-2)

[image: after integrating into the project, source url pointing to the absolute path]

Can anyone tell me, while integrating into my project, why the source url pointing to the absolute path of the solution?

I am struggling here for the last couple of days. Any solution would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, maybe building your project changes the path of the file wrongly.

As a workaround, you can define those plotBands on the second yAxis and set a different width for this axis.

```
{
  linkedTo: 0,
  title: {
    text: ""
  },
  width: 25,
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotBands: [{
      color: 'rgb(204,0,0)',
      from: 0,
      to: 30.99,
      zIndex: 3
    },
    {
      color: 'rgb(226,113,113)',
      from: 31,
      to: 44.99,
      zIndex: 3
    },
    {
      color: 'rgb(247,209,34)',
      from: 45,
      to: 54.99,
      zIndex: 3
    },
    {
      color: 'rgb(136,207,136)',
      from: 55,
      to: 68.99,
      zIndex: 3
    },
    {
      color: 'rgb(68,180,68)',
      from: 69,
      to: 87.99,
      zIndex: 3
    },
    {
      color: 'rgb(0,153,0)',
      from: 88,
      to: 100,
      zIndex: 3
    }
  ],
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1yjwr4ck/